# How to convert a .txt file to .xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

My abc.txt file looks like this:

```
1
76 45 146 87
```

And this is my EXPECTED output showing in xyz.xml file:

```
-<root>
   -<object>
       - <label>1</label>
     </object>
   -<cordinates>
        <xmin>76</xmin>
        <ymin>45</ymin>
        <xmin>146</xmin>
        <xmax>87</xmax>
    </cordinates>
 </root>
```

This is my source code that I have tried:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("root")
object = ET.SubElement(root, "object")
ET.SubElement(object, "label").text = "1"
cordinates = ET.SubElement(root, "cordinates")
ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmin").text = "76"
ET.SubElement(cordinates, "ymin").text = "45"
ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmin").text = "146"
ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmax").text = "87"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("xyz.xml")
```

But the problem is, I have done the labeling and putting the coordinates manually. And I want to extract abc.txt file in this program and do the job automatically for more than 350 .txt files. So can someone please help me re-write the code? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have xmin twice? Should it be xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax ? @Lul

Comment: Yes, Sir. You are right. It was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin with making a function, which takes an `txt_file` and `xml_file` name and inputs, and write the contents of `txt_file` to `xml_file` like so

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def write_xml(txt_file, xml_file):
    label = 0
    text_list = []

    #list of name of coordinates
    coords_list = ['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']

    #Open the text file
    with open(txt_file) as fp:
        #Read the label and text string
        label, text_str = fp.readlines()
        #Create the list of text
        text_list = [item for item in text_str.split()]

    #Create the coordinates dictionary, with key as item of coords_list and values as item of text_list
    coord_dict = dict(zip(coords_list, text_list))

    #Create the xml file
    root = ET.Element("root")
    object = ET.SubElement(root, "object")
    ET.SubElement(object, "label").text = label

    cordinates = ET.SubElement(root, "cordinates")

    #Iterate through the coordinates dictionary and assign the elements
    for key, value in coord_dict.items():
        ET.SubElement(cordinates, key).text = value

    #Write to the xml file
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(xml_file)
```

Then you can call the function as `write_xml('file.txt', 'xyz.xml')`

Now you can call this function for all your txt files in a loop

```
txt_file_paths = [....]
xml_file_paths = [....]

for idx in range(len(txt_file_paths)):
    write_xml(txt_file_paths[idx], xml_file_paths[idx])
```

You can fill up your `txt_file_paths` by listing all files in the txt files folder using `os.listdir`, then create the file path using `os.path.join` and add them to the list

```
import os
txt_files_folder = '<folder_with_txt_files>'
txt_file_names = []

for file in os.listdir(txt_files_folder):

    txt_file_path = os.path.join(txt_files_folder, file)
    txt_file_names.append(txt_file_path)
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you very much for responding. Please be patient with me as I still a newbie. I have your code but I am confused if these three sections of code are to be copy-pasted in a single file or how? I'm getting this error:  **python work3.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work3.py", line 39, in <module>
    write_xml(txt_file_paths[idx], xml_file_paths[idx])
  File "work3.py", line 11, in write_xml
    with open(txt_file) as fp:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/lucy/Downloads/Labels'**

Comment: The first piece of code is a function for converting xml to csv , second piece of code is how you can use that function, and third piece is a way of getting all text files you want to convert in xml? Which piece of code are you getting error? If it is third piece you can add a check to see if full file path contains the string txt also make sure you are giving folder name where you have all txt files present @Lucie

Comment: Hi @Lucie, if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to the answer, else please ask if you have any questions for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will read the object name and coordinated into a dictionary and then iterate over the dictionary to create the corresponding elements that you require.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

file_list = ['abc.txt', 'def.txt']
obj_coord = {}

for file in file_list:
    f = open(file, "r")
    object = f.readline()
    coord_string = f.readline()
    if not coord_string: 
        break
    coord_list = coord_string.split() 
    obj_coord[object] = coord_string
    f.close()


root = ET.Element("root")

for obj, coord in obj_coord.items():
    object = ET.SubElement(root, "object")
    ET.SubElement(object, "label").text = obj 
    cordinates = ET.SubElement(root, "cordinates")
    ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmin").text = coord[0]
    ET.SubElement(cordinates, "ymin").text = coord[1]
    ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmin").text = coord[2]
    ET.SubElement(cordinates, "xmax").text = coord[3]

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("xyz.xml")
```

Comment: Sir,  @razdi Thank you so much for your time. But i have one more issue here. The code works perfectly but is taking a single digit as a coordinate. For e.g: If the four coordinate values are: 12 34 33 66 (there is no commas seperating xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax in this .txt file), then I am getting the output for xmin as 1, ymin as 2, xmax is empty (since there is a space) and ymax is taking 3. It should have showed xmin as 12, ymin as 34, xmax as 33, ymax as 66. So how do i rewrite the code? P.S: please forgive me, I don't know how to do editing properly here

Comment: `<root><label><label>2</label></label><cordinates><xmin>1</xmin><ymin>2 </ymin><xmax> </xmax><ymax>3</ymax></cordinates></root>` This is the output of the xml file.   **secondly**, some .txt files have more than 3-4 rows of values, so how should i display those others rows as well in the same .xml file. Kindly help me, Sir. I am still a noob!

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import os


def toxml(lines, save_filepath):
    def generate_xml(obj, cordinates_arr, save_filepath):
        root_node = ET.Element("root")
        object_node = ET.SubElement(root_node, "object")
        ET.SubElement(object_node, "label").text = obj
        cordinates_node = ET.SubElement(root_node, "cordinates")
        ET.SubElement(cordinates_node, "xmin").text = cordinates_arr[0]
        ET.SubElement(cordinates_node, "ymin").text = cordinates_arr[1]
        ET.SubElement(cordinates_node, "xmin").text = cordinates_arr[2]
        ET.SubElement(cordinates_node, "xmax").text = cordinates_arr[3]
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root_node)
        tree.write(save_filepath)

    if len(lines) != 2:
        print("Invalid content: {}".format(lines))
    obj = lines[0].strip()
    cordinates = lines[1].strip()
    if len(obj) == '' or len(cordinates.split()) != 4:
        print("Invalid line format: {}".format(lines))
    # start generate
    generate_xml(obj, cordinates, save_filepath)

def entry(target_dir_path, save_dri_path):
    assert os.path.exists(target_dir_path), "Target directory is not exist: {}".format(target_dir_path)
    assert os.path.exists(save_dir_path), "Save directory is not exist: {}".format(target_dir_path)

    for filename in os.listdir(target_dir_path):
        file_full_path = os.path.join(target_dir_path, filename)
        filename_prefix, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
        save_path = os.path.join(save_dir_path, "{}.xml".format(filename_prefix))
        try:
            with open(file_full_path) as ff:
                toxml(ff.readlines(), save_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Generate {0} failed, with error msg: {1}.".format(filename, ex.__str__()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    target_dir_path = '/path/to/you/wanna/convert'
    save_dir_path = '/path/to/you/wanna/save'
    entry(target_dir_path, save_dir_path)
```

The code already tested, holp it can help you

Comment: Please add a short description about your answer. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @dobby Thank you Sir for your reply. The code works perfectly but again, there is a problem here. The code is taking a single digit for per coordinate (xmin, ymin, etc..). For e.g: The four coordinate values are: 12 34 33 66, I am getting the output for xmin as 1, ymin as 2, xmax is empty since there is a space and ymax is taking 3. It should have showed xmin as 12, ymin as 34, xmax as 33, ymax as 66.So how do i rewrite the code? P.S: please forgive me, I dont know how to do editing properly here.

Comment: @dobby In the .txt file, there is no comma separating the values of xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax. So, maybe thats the reason for showing wrong output in .xml file.   And **second issue** is, some .txt files contain more than 3-4 rows, in this case, how should i read the next rows automatically? Kindly help me Sir.

Comment: This code only supports for you put the question before, The second line in u txt has 4 value split with space, and they correctly aimed at cordinates_node's 4 sub-nodes. So, if other formats, you have to let me know what is it, and aim to whose sub-nodes name.@Lucie